# Why a specific \color does not work on \author?

Tags: beamer, color, presentations, author

On beamer document class, in the part of \author does not let me put an specific color.

I have

```
\author{\pink{ my name} \\ other name}
```

Specifically does not work with \pink but it does for \blue,\green, etc.

Also I indicate to put color only on `{my name}` but it automatically put color on `{other name}`, why?

I am using `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`

Help me please

Comment: Please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried.

Comment: You might be interested in using the `\textcolor` command.

Comment: How is `\pink` defined? This is no macro that is defined per default.

Comment: @leandriis where do I put the command `\textcolor` ?

Comment: @samcarter I don't understand what you mean, I haven't used that color before

Comment: The general usage of the command is as follows: `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}` Applied to your case this would be `\textcolor{pink}{ my name}`

Comment: @leandriis Thank you, it worked!

Comment: @leandriis One more question, notice I used `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` so that I could have more options for colors but is does not work for those other colors, it leaves as it is, in black color. How to fix it?

Comment: @user178403: As already mentioned, a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  would be very helpful to see what code you use and where possible errors come from. Using `\usepackage[divsnames]{xcolor}` in combination with the `beamer` documentclass will by the way generate an error message which should in general not be ignored.

Comment: @user178403 If you want to use `dvipsnames` with beamer: `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}`, but you will still need to use the proper colour syntax, either `\textcolor{pink}{...}` or `{\color{pink}....}`.

Comment: @samcarter Thank you so much, now it recognize the other colors, and my 40-s errors where reduced to 18-s :)

Comment: @user178403 Never ignore error messages. Fix all 18 errors before you try to further customise your presentation.

Comment: @samcarter Yes I will, now there are only 11, the funny thing is that even with 11 errors still displays what it should be displaying. Kinda weird.

Comment: @user178403 No, it does not display what it should display. After an error tex only recovers enough to finish the job, not necessarily producing a sensible document. Even if you think it looks right, there could still be problems.

Comment: @samcarter: Would you mind adding your last comment to [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/134144)?

Comment: @leandriis Having a text building block about not ignoring error messages might indeed be a very good idea. However there are probably better worded comments out there which might be better suited. I think I once read a well written comment by @ DavidCarlisle, I'll try to find it again.

Comment: @leandriis I proposed something: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8195/36296 Please feel free to edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` with the `beamer` documentclass will result in an eror message. The correct usage is the following: `\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}`.

In order to color a certain text, you have the following possibilities:

a) The `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}` command:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\author{\textcolor{pink}{my name} \\ other name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

b) The `\color{<color>}`  switch that is active inside a group or until a different `\color` switch is used:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\author{{\color{pink} my name} \\ other name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

c) Define your own `\pink{<text>}` command using `\newcommand` as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\newcommand{\pink}[1]{\textcolor{pink}{#1}}
\author{\pink{my name} \\ other name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```